# Obtener elemento mayoritario de un vector

Tags: python

Necesito ayuda para resolver este problema de elemento mayoritario en Python

```py
A=[6,10,2,1,10,20,15,6,3] #Vector
n= len(A) #Alías del vector

def MAY(A):
    for i in n:
        k= APA(A,A[i],i+1,n) #Función
        if k+1 > n/2:
            return A[i]
    return 0

~ ~ ~    
def APA(A,x,i,j): #Aparaciones
    c=0
    for i in range(0,len(A)-1):
        if A[i]==x:
            c=c+1
    return c
```

En la función de def APA quisiera saber si estoy bien. Disculpen, pero es mi primera publicación.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: ¿Qué entiendes por "mayoritario"? En el código que propones (aunque no funciona) se ve un `k+1> n/2` que parece sugerir que buscas un elemento que aparezca en mayoría absoluta (la mitad más uno de los elementos). No hay tal elemento en el ejemplo que das pues los que más veces aparecen (el 10 y el 6) lo hacen solo dos veces. Otra interpretación (la de mi respuesta), es buscar una mayoría simple, o sea, el elemento qué más veces se repite (aunque no sea la mitad más uno). En cambio, en la respuesta que has aceptado  se busca el máximo, que no es nada de lo anterior, ni encaja con "mayoritario".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entiendo que buscas el elemento que más se repite en tu lista (aunque en el ejemplo que das habría un empate entre el 6 y el 10 ¿cuál deberías retornar?)

La biblioteca estándar python tiene muchas funciones útiles para resolver problemas frecuentes y este es uno de ellos. En el módulo `collections` tienes la clase `Counter()` que te cuenta el número de apariciones de cada elemento, algo como lo que querías hacer en tu función `A()`, pero mucho más genérico y a la vez más rápido por estar internamente implementado en C en vez de Python. Se usaría así:

```
from collections import Counter
A=[6,10,2,1,10,20,15,6,3] #Vector

cuenta = Counter(A)
```

El resultado `cuenta` es un diccionario cuyas claves son los elementos de `A` (sin repeticiones) y los valores el número de veces que apareció cada clave. En este caso `cuenta` valdría:

```
{6: 2, 10: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 20: 1, 15: 1}
```

Es más, en realidad `cuenta` es un objeto de la clase `Counter()` que tiene algunos métodos útiles, como por ejemplo recuperar el que más veces haya aparecido, así:

```
>>> cuenta.most_common(1)
[(6,2)]
```

O los dos más frecuentes:

```
>>> cuenta.most_common(2)
[(6, 2), (10, 2)]
```

En esta lista cada pareja contiene el dato y el número de veces que apareció.

Si por cualquier razón quisieras implementar tú mismo en python una solución a este problema, que no use `Counter()`, sino en "python puro", acláralo en un comentario para que pueda darte otra solución. Tu código es muy ineficiente y además incorrecto.

Answer (score 1):

Te estás complicando demasiado. Python tiene el método `max()` que pasándole una lista te devuelve el número más grande, `max(A)` en tu caso. Si lo que quieres es implementar el código desde 0 una solución sería así:

```
def max_num_in_list(A):
    max = list[0]
    for num in list:
        if num > max:
            max = num
    return max
```

Asignamos el primer número de la lista a la variable `max` y vamos recorriendo número a número, si el número que estamos recorriendo es mayor que `max`, entonces `max = número que estamos recorriendo`, de tal forma que cuando terminemos de recorrer la lista `max` contendrá el número mayor.